# Why won't wxWidgets work with Code::Blocks + minGW?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, codeblocks

How would I make wxWidgets 2.9.4 work with Code::Blocks + MinGW? I have built the libraries (release only) and coded some code. When I build it **without event tables** it works fine, but with them, it throws errors.

Here is a dump of the build messages when there are event tables:

```
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `_ZN21wxEventTableEntryBaseC2EiiP14wxEventFunctorP8wxObject':|
C:\wxWidgets\include\wx\event.h|2870|undefined reference to `_wxTheAssertHandler'|
C:\wxWidgets\include\wx\event.h|2871|undefined reference to `wxOnAssert(char const*, int, char const*, char const*, char const*)'|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `_ZN20wxEventFunctorMethodI14wxEventTypeTagI14wxCommandEventE12wxEvtHandler7wxEventS3_EC1EMS3_FvRS4_EPS3_':|
C:\wxWidgets\include\wx\event.h|374|undefined reference to `_wxTheAssertHandler'|
C:\wxWidgets\include\wx\event.h|374|undefined reference to `wxOnAssert(char const*, int, char const*, char const*, char const*)'|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `_ZN20wxEventFunctorMethodI14wxEventTypeTagI14wxCommandEventE12wxEvtHandler7wxEventS3_EclEPS3_RS4_':|
C:\wxWidgets\include\wx\event.h|392|undefined reference to `_wxTheAssertHandler'|
C:\wxWidgets\include\wx\event.h|392|undefined reference to `wxOnAssert(char const*, int, char const*, char const*, char const*)'|
||=== Build finished: 6 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

and another of the build log:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in G1BC ---------------

Compiling: main.cpp
Linking executable: bin\Debug\G1BC.exe
obj\Debug\main.o: In function `_ZN21wxEventTableEntryBaseC2EiiP14wxEventFunctorP8wxObject':
C:/wxWidgets/include/wx/event.h:2870: undefined reference to `_wxTheAssertHandler'
C:/wxWidgets/include/wx/event.h:2871: undefined reference to `wxOnAssert(char const*, int, char const*, char const*, char const*)'
obj\Debug\main.o: In function `_ZN20wxEventFunctorMethodI14wxEventTypeTagI14wxCommandEventE12wxEvtHandler7wxEventS3_EC1EMS3_FvRS4_EPS3_':
C:/wxWidgets/include/wx/event.h:374: undefined reference to `_wxTheAssertHandler'
C:/wxWidgets/include/wx/event.h:374: undefined reference to `wxOnAssert(char const*, int, char const*, char const*, char const*)'
obj\Debug\main.o: In function `_ZN20wxEventFunctorMethodI14wxEventTypeTagI14wxCommandEventE12wxEvtHandler7wxEventS3_EclEPS3_RS4_':
C:/wxWidgets/include/wx/event.h:392: undefined reference to `_wxTheAssertHandler'
C:/wxWidgets/include/wx/event.h:392: undefined reference to `wxOnAssert(char const*, int, char const*, char const*, char const*)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 4 seconds)
6 errors, 0 warnings
```

Code::Blocks says this bit of code is the problem:
     [image: The bad code]

Hope you can help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Try building wxWidgets in debug since all the errors your getting are for the assert functions which is only in debug.

Comment: There is no Problem in marked area. The problem is in makefile. you are missing Libraries. These are all Linker Errors.

Answer (score 1):

You need to always leave `DEBUG_FLAG=1` as **that**, otherwise asserts won't compile.

This is what it says in MSW's install.txt:

> Specifies the level of debug support in wxWidgets. Notice that   this
>   is independent from both BUILD and DEBUG_INFO options. **By default  always set to 1 meaning that > debug support is enabled: asserts are
>   compiled   into the code (they are inactive by default in release
>   builds of the   application but can be enabled),** wxLogDebug() and
>   wxLogTrace() are available and **WXDEBUG** is defined. Setting it to
>   0 completely disables all debugging code in wxWidgets while setting
>   it to 2 enables even the time   consuming assertions and checks which
>   are deemed to be unsuitable for   production environment.